# How can I call "search()" on an element that has jQuery autocomplete bound to it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm just putting together in my head how jQuery and widgets and elements fit together. I have a combobox that uses autocomplete. I have set up a JSON remote data source and that is working fabulously. What I am trying to do is force the user to select from the box, a pretty common occurrence I think.

Upon selection of a value in the autocomplete combobox, the input element bound to autocomplete receives the id value of the selection. So I will check for the presence of a value there by binding a function to the "autocompleteclose" event.

The only thing I'm missing is, how to I call the "search" method on that input field again? I can't call the function on an element, like this:

```
$("#myinputfield").search();
```

because I get the message:

```
$("#myinputfield").search() is not a function
```

I get that, I guess, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger the event handler with the [`autocompletesearch`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#events) event:

```
$("#myinputfield").trigger("autocompletesearch");
```

Comment: jQuery UI - v1.11.4. without trigger **autocompletesearch**. Use `$("#myinputfield").autocomplete("search", $("#myinputfield").val());`

Answer (score 2):

You can call methods on a $.Widget like autocomplete like this

```
$('#myinputfield').autocomplete( 'search', 'myvalue' );
```